# How to save value for foreign keys?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I want save the ID of the selected `subjectname` in a `DataGridView` and also the ID of the student whose year level is selected in the combobox. So my reference for getting the student and subject is the school year and the year level. I want to save it in my table Schedule which has `Registration_registrationID` (FK), `Student_studentID` (FK), `yearlevel` and `schoolyear`:

Here's my code :

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string reg = "";
        string schoolyear = txt_startYr.Text +  "-" + txt_endYr.Text;
        MySqlConnection conn, conn1, conn2;
        MySqlCommand cmd2;
        MySqlDataReader reader, reader1;

        List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from row in dg_subjects.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value) == true select row).ToList();

        if (selectedRows.Count >= 1)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Are you sure you want to add this subject?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
                {
                    try
                    {                      
                       conn = new MySqlConnection(myconn);
                       conn.Open();
                       string subject = "Select subjectID from southpoint_school.subject WHERE subject_name = '" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "';";
                       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(subject, conn);
                       reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                       reader.Read();
                       string subj = reader.GetString("subjectID");
                       conn.Close();

                       conn1 = new MySqlConnection(myconn);
                       conn1.Open();
                       string query = "Select regID from southpoint_school.registration where yearLevel =  '" + cmb_year.Text + "' AND  schoolYear = '" + schoolyear + "';";
                       MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, conn1);
                       reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                       while (reader1.Read())
                       {

                           conn2 = new MySqlConnection(myconn);
                           reg = reader1.GetString("regID");
                           string query1 = "INSERT INTO southpoint_school.schedule (Registration_regID, Subject_subjectID, yearLevel, school_year) values ('" + reg + "','" + subj + "','" + cmb_year.Text + "','"  + schoolyear + "')";
                           cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(query1, conn2);
                           conn2.Open();
                           cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           MessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved");
                           conn2.Close();
                       }
                       conn1.Close();
                  }



                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                  }
            }
        }

        else
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please select a Subject");
        }

      }
```

It doesn't give an error but it does nothing.

Comment: Do any of the MessageBoxes appear? Do you see this when you click the Add button? "Are you sure you want to add this subject?"

Comment: yes it appears. I think there's a problem in the while loop part

Comment: Are you trying to include the # of selected rows in the MessageBox text? I don't see any placeholders - string.Format("Are you sure you want to add this subject?", selectedRows.Count)

Comment: no.. my problem is : the selected items are not saving in the database

Comment: I am a Web Developer so I am not very familiar with the ComboBox, but ..., are you expecting the user to enter some text or choose an item  from the DropDownList? I think a ComboBox will allow the user to do either one, but getting the value will be different.

Comment: I found this on another site - In combobox Text and SelectedItem are two very different things: 1. comboBox.Text: This property returns the value of the text types in the combobox by user (if he/she types something). 2. comboBox.SelectedItem: This property returns the value the user selects by using the drop down menu.

Comment: So are you sure you want to use the .Text property here?? where yearLevel =  '" + cmb_year.Text + "' AND

Comment: after he select year level, all the students with that year level will be tagged by the subjects selected in the datagridview